# ASP.NET Gridview that resizes with browser window?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, autoresize

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?  The closet I've gotten was some code that added scrollbars to the gridview, but I don't know enough about CSS to know whether or not dynamically resizing gridviews are possible.

EDIT:
To be clear, it should be resize by width *and* height.

Comment: what about `width=100%` unless you hard-coded width into your columns

Answer (score 1):

you can use css,

```
.someclass
{
width:100%;
}
```

or else width property of gridview,

```
width="100%"
```

Comment: Does this apply to height as well?  The gridview is about halfway down the page.

Comment: Then unfortunately it doesn't really solve the problem :\  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Actually why you need 100% width? :D As the content grows gridview height will also increase.

Comment: I want the height to decrease with the window size as well.  I already know how to add the scrollbars, now I just need the bottom of the bottome edge gridview to remain static in relation to the bottom of the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

write css class

```
.flextable{ width:70%;}
```

set CssClass="flextable" of gridiview

it results gridiview 70% width of browser window